# Django 2.x drf-yasg how to create API in a custom method (like in swagger)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger, drf-yasg

I am migrating my Django 1.11.7 to 2.x. One of the problems is django-rest-swagger, it is now deprecated. And drf-yasg should now be the way for the API documentation and creation. I need to do it in a similar way of creating custom api as so it doesnt break anything in the mobile.

Previously, it looks like this (django-rest-swagger==2.1.1)

[image: old deprecated swagger 2.1.1]
here is the old code snippet that works nicely in Django 1.11.7 and django-rest-swagger==2.1.1:

```
using swagger_schema.py
https://gist.github.com/axilaris/2f72fef8f30c56d5befe9e31cd76eb50


in url.py:

from rest_framework_swagger.views import get_swagger_view
from myapp.swagger_schema import SwaggerSchemaView


urlpatterns = [  
   url(r'^swaggerdoc/', SwaggerSchemaView.as_view()),
   url(r'^api/v1/general/get_countries$', api.get_countries, name='get_countries'),


in api.py:
@api_view(['POST'])
def get_countries(request):
    # ----- YAML below for Swagger -----
    """
    description: countries list
    parameters:
      - name: token
        type: string
        required: true
        location: form   
    """
    ......
    return Response(countries_list, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

My question is how to do it in drf-yasg similarly, as I want to migrate this code and dont break anything on the mobile.

probably try to do this on this latest stable releases:

```
djangorestframework==3.9
drf-yasg==1.16.1
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it like this in your `api.py`. This will generate exactly what you show in the screenshot:

```
from drf_yasg import openapi
from drf_yasg.utils import swagger_auto_schema

from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, parser_classes
from rest_framework.parsers import FormParser

token = openapi.Parameter('token', openapi.IN_FORM, type=openapi.TYPE_STRING, required=True)


@swagger_auto_schema(
    method="post",
    manual_parameters=[token]
)
@api_view(["POST"])
@parser_classes([FormParser])
def get_countries(request):
    """
    Countries list
    """
    ......
    return Response(countries_list, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Note that I added `@parser_classes([FormParser])` decorator to make sure the view accepts form data. You can remove it if all your endpoints work only with form data and you [set it globally in DRF settings](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/).

Result:
[image: result]

[Here's more documentation on @swagger_auto_schema decorator](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom_spec.html#the-swagger-auto-schema-decorator).

Comment: works brilliantly! thanks. I want to ask one a bit further question, how to handle file uploads ? previously i did it this way https://gist.github.com/axilaris/779f8cc88a4f5fadbf4fd3b88006c4f3. What should be the parameters be given for file ?

Comment: @Axil declare the parameter under the token one like this: `company_logo = openapi.Parameter('company_logo', openapi.IN_FORM, type=openapi.TYPE_FILE, required=True)` and then add it into the `manual_parameters` list inside the decorator like so: `manual_parameters=[token, company_logo]`. It is the same thing, just that you have to use `openapi.TYPE_FILE` instead of `TYPE_STRING`.